# Blender 2.8 Metaballs update 'never' is not working, seems to always update even with never turned on

Tags: meta-objects

I have a complex network of metaballs that I generate using my python script. I would like to (as I do in 2.79) set the UPDATE property to 'NEVER' while I'm generating them; vastly improving speed. This works in 2.79b:

```
bpy.ops.object.metaball_add(type = 'CAPSULE',rotation = (0,-pi/2,0))
medge = bpy.context.object
medge.data.update_method = 'NEVER'
```

BUT, it **doesn't** work in 2.8 or 2.81.

The metaballs seem to be 'stuck' on ALWAYS. 
I tried just making a couple generic metaballs and setting to NEVER using the gui, but they still appear!!!

Am i missing something or is there a problem with the NEVER setting in 2.8 ?

Thanks for *any* suggestions or info. This is kind of mission critical.

Also, I would like to ask if anyone knows how I can improve the metaball generation blender code. I have 2.8 compiled in VS code. I'm no cpp expert but it's working.
I'd really like to make metaballs from additional primitives such as triangles.
Right now there are metaball cubes and planes, but not triangle.

I know I should ask on blender forums but thought I'd ask here too.
I have some funding for this work if that matters.

Thanks and any help much appreciated.

Comment: Look like a bug to me. Please report this on the bug tracker

Comment: I've just checked `bpy.data.objects["Mball"].data.update_method` does return the value set, however it doesn't seem to have any effect on the viewport updates.

Comment: Thanks, at least I'm not going crazy then :)

Comment: I've submitted a bug report on the blender forum.